# Save new form of custom ArrayList, SharedPreferences

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

noobie here. I have a custum ArrayAdapter with questions and answers. When one list item is longClicked, it gets removed. Now I want to save the new state of the ArrayList with the removed item, so if you go to another tab in the app and then return you will have only the remaining questions. 
I looked online and found something that looks like what I need, but I can't see why it won't work.

```
public class OnePointQuestion extends AppCompatActivity {
ArrayList<Question> TheQuestion;
String key = "ABCD";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.list);

    if(TheQuestion == null){
        createList();
    }else{
        getArrayList(key);
    }

    final MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(this, TheQuestion);
    ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    //When the list item is clicked
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Identify the current question
            Question currentQuestion = TheQuestion.get(position);

            //Send the answer to a second page to be shown
            Intent i = new Intent(OnePointQuestion.this, TheAnswer.class);
            i.putExtra("TheAnswer", currentQuestion.getAnswer());
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    //When the list item is long clicked
    listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Identify the current question
            Question currentQuestion = TheQuestion.get(position);
            //Remove this element of the list
            TheQuestion.remove(currentQuestion);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            Toast.makeText(OnePointQuestion.this, "Urmatoarea intrebare", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

//Save the ArrayList
public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<Question> list, String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OnePointQuestion.this);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    editor.putString(key, json);
    editor.apply();     // This line is IMPORTANT !!!
    Toast.makeText(OnePointQuestion.this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//Load the ArrayList
public ArrayList<Question> getArrayList(String key){
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(OnePointQuestion.this);
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
    Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Question>>() {}.getType();
    Toast.makeText(OnePointQuestion.this, "Loaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return gson.fromJson(json, type);
}

//Load the ArrayList when the app gets to the OnStart
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    getArrayList(key);
}


@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveArrayList(TheQuestion, key);
}


public void createList(){
    //Create the list of questions
    TheQuestion = new ArrayList<>();
    TheQuestion.add(new Question("Cum te cheama?", "Irelevant"));
    TheQuestion.add(new Question("Cati ani ai?", "Prea multi"));
    TheQuestion.add(new Question("De ce ai dat la Poli", "Asta ma intreb si eu"));

}
```

}

The "save" and "load" methods I'm trying to use are near the end. 
If you can tell me what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate it, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Move `getArrayList(key);` to onResume() method.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    getArrayList(key);
}
```

see the life cycle:

[image]

Comment: It still won't work. It tells me something that the return value of the getArrayList(key) is not used. I have tried to use it some how, but it would crush my app..